# Google certificate gcp.gvt2.com untrusted / expired?

Tags: google, certificate-revocation

My antivirus noted gcp.gvt2.com certificate is expired today, gvt2.com alegently used by google analytics.
It might to do with Google distrust of Symantec https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html. Is that possible that google is late updating its own certificates?

[image]

Comment: 3 month cert? What website gave this to you?

Comment: It is not a website but one or few Windows services via ports 443 and 80 as I recall, such as Google Update or windows certificates update service. I’ve got to go back through logs to figure out yet.

Comment: Strange certificate - issued by 'GTS CA 101' - whatever this CA is. Does not look like a public CA or common intermediate CA, maybe some firewall doing SSL interception?

Answer (score 1):

No, that the certificate expired today (as shown in the screenshot) is unrelated to the Symantec untrust.

> Is that possible that google is late updating its own certificates?

Well, it is possible.

Note that gcp.gvt2.com doesn't resolve here, though.

Comment: Top domain not resolved but registered on Google and subdomains apparently actively used.

Comment: I'd even argue that it's plausible, given that their [GPG Signing Key expired recently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551). Given how Google is structured internally, it's very plausible that they just forgot.